# Does SVG text generated by Javascript get indexed by search engines?

Tags: html, seo, svg

I am concerned about doing a product animated presentation with SVG. The planed animation is a little too complex to be achieved with regular DOM manipulation (non SVG) and of course canvas is not an alternative since the content has to be indexed by Search engines. The animation is already mocked up and follows a typographic style.

That concern comes from the fact that I don't know if dynamic generated and injected text inside SVG will be indexed by search engines with the same richness other DOM elements will, or if it will be indexed at all!?

Would be good to know if somebody here already managed this situation, in practice, and if the indexing happened as expected (although any good and well documented hypothesis could help). In negative case, alternative solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - it won't be in your page when it is crawled. If you want content to be indexed, serve it up straight from the server.